# Непонятное происхождение значения http заголовка

Tags: javascript, c#, парсер, http, бот

решили написать небольшой бот для одного сайта и запоролись на авторизации. В http запросе есть заголовки с значениями непонятного происхождения (x-instana-t и x-instana-s, хотя они одинаковые), есть догадка что оно составляется где-то в js коде, но мы так и не смогли найти где, код привязанный к кнопке ни о чем не говорит (определение функции decibelInsight так и не нашли, и используется она везде). Хотели бы получить хотя бы наводку на то как получить это значение.
[image: Сам запрос]

```
function setSubmitEventListener(sel, name, submissionSelector) {
    var form = document.querySelector(sel);
    var submissionButton = document.querySelector(submissionSelector);
    if (form && submissionButton) {
        submissionButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
            decibelInsight('formSubmitted', sel);
        });
    }
}
```

Код аутентификации:

```
static string AuthAdidas(string login, string password) {

    HttpClientHandler ClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(), UseCookies = true };
    HttpClient Client = new HttpClient(ClientHandler);

    HtmlDocument Document = new HtmlDocument();

    JsonObject JObj = new JsonObject();

    JObj.Add("user", login);
    JObj.Add("password", password);
    JObj.Add("isMobile", false);

    HttpContent PostContent = new StringContent(JObj.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    HttpRequestMessage PostReq = new HttpRequestMessage()
    {

        Method = HttpMethod.Post,

        RequestUri = new Uri(@"https://www.adidas.ru/api/account/login%22"),


        Headers = {
            { "Connection", "keep-alive" },
            // { "X-INSTANA-T", "a1dc58d998e770b" },
            // { "X-INSTANA-S", "a1dc58d998e770b" },
            { "sec-ch-ua-mobile", "?0" },
            { "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36" },
            { "sec-ch-ua", "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"90\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"90\"" },
            { "X-INSTANA-L", "1,correlationType = web;correlationId=a1dc58d998e770b" },
            { "Sec-Fetch-Site", "same-origin" },
            { "Sec-Fetch-Mode", "cors" },
            { "Sec-Fetch-Dest", "empty" },
            { "Referer", @"https://www.adidas.ru/account-login" },
Content = PostContent

    };

    HttpResponseMessage PostResult = Client.SendAsync(PostReq).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    string Result = Client.GetStringAsync("https://www.adidas.ru/my-account%22").GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    Document.LoadHtml(Result);

    HtmlNode NameNode = Document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@manual_cmsp='header--customerinfo-_-username']");

    return NameNode.InnerHtml;

}
```

Comment: Не всегда запросу нужны все данные, которые передает браузер. Вы пробовали без этого заголовка? Я допустим отправил пустой запрос и получил [это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLNjB.png), как видите, у меня ваших заголовков вовсе нету.  Или вы входите через соц. сеть? Если да, то тогда вам надо сначала разобрать как она работает, а уж затем ваш основной сайт.

Comment: Да, пробовали без, сервер отвечает <Request is not completed.  waiting...>
Проверили с HTTP Analyzer
https://imgur.com/mEttjkm

Comment: Переформулируйте пожалуйста вопрос так, чтобы было понятно, какой ответ вы ожидаете.

Comment: Благодарю, исправил

Comment: Кстати, `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` - оно вообще работает? По идее не должно, должно виснуть намертво. Просто оставлю это здесь - [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

Comment: `correlationType = web` - 2 лишних пробела здесь.

Comment: По поводу .GetAwaiter().GetResult(), пока что все сделано в виде консольного приложения, это не сильно заметно.
correlationType = web - исправил, ответ тот же, благодарю за предложение в любом случае